# Batch Download Picture

Tags: windows-10, batch-file, download, pictures

Why isn't this code working?

```
   :downloadPicture
   bitsadmin /transfer downloadPicture  /download /priority normal  https://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/foggygoldengatebridge.jpg  C:\Users\%username%\desktop\%pictureName%
```

It's giving me an error saying that the server does not support the necessary HTTP protocol. Thanks!
By the way, this is just part of the project. I set `pictureName` somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

The full message is something like this:

```
DISPLAY: downloadPicture TYPE: DOWNLOAD STATE: ERROR
PRIORITY: NORMAL FILES: 0 / 1 BYTES: 0 / 17873 (0%)
Unable to complete transfer.
ERROR FILE:    https://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/foggygoldengatebridge.jpg -> C:\Users\ouroborus\desktop\%pictureName%
ERROR CODE:    0x80200013 - The server does not support the necessary HTTP protocol. Background Intelligent Transfer Service (BITS) requires that the server support the Range protocol header.
ERROR CONTEXT: 0x00000005 - The error occurred while the remote file was being processed.
```

It's pretty clear what's going on: `bitsadmin` requires that the server supports `Range` headers and planwallpaper.com doesn't have that support.

Use something else like [`wget`](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm) or [`curl`](http://www.confusedbycode.com/curl/).

Comment: Note that you can test for range support by running HEAD on the page, and looking for the response 206 (PARTIAL CONTENT).